# Timezone with symfony 2

Tags: macos, symfony, timezone, php

I've got some troubles whith Symfony 2, trying to generate schema via :

```
php console/app generate:schema:create
```

I've got a pretty error :

```
[Exception]                           
DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's 
timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone 
setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.

In case you used any of those methods and you are still 
getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone 
identifier. 

We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead
```

Thus, I'm trying to change the timezone in my php.ini with

```
date.timezone = 'Europe/Paris'
```

but even if I'm reloading my apache, I still get

```
date.timezone   Europe/Zurich   Europe/Zurich
```

if I look at my `phpinfo()`, so I don't really know what should I try next ... And I'm not even sure that I'm in the good way.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: is Apache using the php.ini that you are changing?  Depending on your setup you may also need to configure it for more than one php.ini (one for main, one for Cli).  For example, if you're using MAMP, your console commands should probably look more like this:
php -c /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/ app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: I'm not using MAMP and I used the command `echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` in my php_info() file to be sure I was working with the good one.

Comment: what do you get if you do a php --ini on the command line?

Comment: Interesting I have `Thomas@~ $ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)`
So I looked into /etc and I have a php.ini.default which should be used in my terminal. Should I just make a ln -s to link to my real php.ini ?

Comment: Okay, I tried using `ln -s`, copying, ... now when I do `php --info | grep timezone` I have Europe\Paris. The problem is that I still have the error using symfony 2 `php app/console doctrine:schema:create`. And my php.ini seems not to be the same on localhost ...

Comment: php -c /Path/to/php.ini_folder/ app/console command

Comment: This hack worked for me: [mikecroteau.wordpress.com](http://mikecroteau.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/symfony2-doctrine-datetime__construct-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On mac, if you have `/etc/php.ini.default`, do

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

and then do

```
php --ini
```

to see that it now loads a php.ini file.

Comment: You saved me a lot of hours +1

Comment: i found the setting in an additional file /usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini

Comment: @MonstersX, you saved me! +100500!

Answer (score 2):

this that trick

and se `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

`datetime = 'America/Lima'` for example

and run command

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite 
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Some third-party distributions of PHP (including MAMP) have hard-coded the timezone. For instance, MAMP 2.0 is hard-coded to Europe/Berlin, and there is no way to change this. Even changing the value in the php.ini template has no effect, because MAMP overwrites your value. Are you using PHP from source, a pre-compiled package, or PHP as a part of some kind of LAMP stack?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on debian based, you must modify the parameter in the file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini, changing it in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old ticket, but since I was having a problem with this too, and it's still open I thought I'd share my quick 'n' dirty solution:

In my case, `date.default` was not set at all and I wasn't in a position to change `php.ini`. So, as a stopgap I added `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin')` at the start of `web/app.php` to change the timezone at runtime, which worked nicely for me.

If you're using the console to run any commands you will probably have to add the call to the the top of this script also.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I installed XAMPP for the webserver and downloaded PHP and installed it so that I could run the symfony commands from command prompt.

In this case, the `php.ini` file used when I execute a Symfony command is located in `C:\Program Files(x86)\PHP\php.ini`. You have to have admin rights in order to edit this file, so I launched Notepad++ as administrator and opened the file.

Look for `date.timezone` and modify it according to your timezone e.g. `date.timezone = Africa/Nairobi`. Timezones are listed on the php website, just search `php, timezones`. No need to restart your computer or webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with my shared host. they told me I couldn't change time zones via php.ini, but you can try an **`.htaccess`** file instead.

create the `.htaccess` in the folder where Symfony is installed and put the following code in it:

```
SetEnv TZ America/Sao_Paulo
```

hope this helps.

cheers, 
Luciano

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem with XAMPP on Mac 10.11.5, PHP 5.6.8

My error read "Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): Invalid date.timezone value 'America/Los Angeles',"

I fixed it by finding the only problem was the missing underscore in the "Los Angeles" entry for my PHP.ini date.timezone setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this command:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini /etc/php.ini

Mac in my case. 
First - config path, second - don't change.